# Information on 3D Transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

This is not so much a question as it is an information. I failed to find such a simple solution to this problem after 2 days' of head scratching on google and thought I might just as well place it here for someone else who might be having the same problem:

When using a 3D transformation for an object in css, you MUST follow these rules:

1. You must add the perspective property. By default it's none, so you need to add one to see the 3D effect.
2. You must add "px" or "%" or "em" next to the perspective, otherwise it will NOT work in Firefox.

   ```
   -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
   ```
3. You must add -webkit- prefix for it to work in Chrome. Chrome does not accept transform without prefix if it has perspective in it.
4. Add the perspective property to the container div of the object you want to transform. Easiest way to do so is just add it to the body during css reset or just add it manually if you are not resetting. This prevents the bug in ios Safari.

I realize that this information might get outdated pretty soon. But I still wanted to just place it here, in case someone else has been facing the same problems as I was (The issue 2 was the one that I could not find an answer to).

If you are trying to access the style in javascript try this:

```
elementID.style.transform = "perspective("+value+"px) " + ....
elementID.style.webkitTransform = "perspective("+value+"px) " + ....
elementID.style.MozTransform = "perspective("+value+"px) " + ....
```

for moz, M is capitalized.

Comment: Most of this info won't be outdated pretty soon ... It's already outdated. Besides, you don't need to set both prespective funcion and perspective style, use only one (and the **meaning** of one and the other is different )

Comment: It is already outdated? Why, is there a newer css property that you can use to do 3D transformations? Is the latest version of Chrome capable of working without the webkit prefix? Does the latest version of Firefox work without the "px" in perspective? Does ios Safari work without using perspective on the parent div? So, no, these are not outdated yet. But I am hoping that in their future updates, the browsers are going to fix these limitations.

And no, you don't need to set both of them and I never said that you do. I could not find these solutions in a batch, so I thought I'd put it here.

Comment: -moz-transform was last required for FF 15. The latest version is 48 ...For Chromw, latest version requiring prefix is 35, latest 52.  And Chrome can work with perspective without -webkit- prefix without any problem.

Comment: In chrome 52, transform works without prefix. But not when using perspective. Just tried it to confirm and I am using the latest version. I can confirm it for chrome Version 52.0.2743.116. The transformation just does not show up and the styles are strikethrough'd in the element inspector.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong information. Did another testing and found out that the issue is only with if you add the style using Element inspector. If it's in the CSS, it works fine. Doing some more digging showed up that it's a bug in Chrome and sometimes it even crosses the style out even when it's working. But that's when you add it from the element inspector. Works fine if you have added it in CSS.